# how to detect missed acknowledge in socket.io client

Tags: unity-game-engine, socket.io, callback, emit

i used socket.io and node.js for server and i used unity socket.io for client in my game.
now, my question is, How can I be notified when client missed receive acknowledge.
for example, client emit this:

```
socket.Emit("testClient", data,ackCallBack);// client emit testClient to server

// get acknowledge in this callback method
public void ackCallBack(JSONObject data)
{
    Debug.Log("---------ackCallBack----------" + data);
}
```

but i cant detect if acknowledge missed.
How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about client/server architectures but I believe socket.io use TCP, therefore if a packet is lost it is sent again.

Again I'm not 100% confident about this subject, wait for network guru to come by x)